# Finding address in IDA from address found in Cheat Engine

Tags: ida, disassembly, x86, cheat-engine

I found a pointer's address, `0x485FE058`, in Cheat Engine. However, when I load up the exe in IDA, the addresses are smaller and start from `0x00401000`. I read up somewhere that this was called virtual memory addresses. But, after looking, I couldn't figure out how to plug the dynamic addresses in Cheat Engine and make them show up.

Answer (score 2):

Edit -> Segment-> Rebase in IDA and input the address where it is *actually* loaded in CheatEngine

You will have one-to-one-correspondence.

Comment: I get that the rebase will work if I know the position of the *same instruction* in IDA and the position of *the exact same instruction line* in memory. ... But Cheat Engine unfortunately does not provide a mapping of the whole binary (unless I miss something).
In that regard, how to know what the lines of the memory correspond to in the binary ? I guess I could trying making a search of binary values near by copying the bytes in CE where there is the function I want to modify.. :/